# Shared SQL Database on UNC Share with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, unc

I have an application that uses Entity Framework 6 and an SQL database.

The application has been built and tested on my local machine which is on a large corporate company network.

The database needs to be available to a handful of users (usually one user at any time) but the only shared "space" is a UNC share. I believe this isn't possible with my set up.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and SQL Server Management Studio 2014 so can't use SQL Compact Edition (SQL Compact Toolbox is for VS Pro only).

Do I have any options here? An earlier version of the application used an Access Database but I really don't want to go back to this.

Comment: Do you not have access to a SQL Server that this database can be hosted on? Maybe even a SQL Express instance?

Comment: @DB101 I do on my local machine i have 'GBABC08390834\SQLEXPRESS', where GBABC08390834 is my computer name. The problem arises if I put the database on the unc share. It then becomes invisble to my instance. I can set permissions on the database file for my computer but still no access.

Comment: You are going about it in the wrong way. You can either use your machine as the SQL Server to host the database or you can use another machine that has SQL Server installed on it to host the database. Moving the mdb file around is not the the correct way. Have a look at the thread below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599211/sql-server-database-on-unc-share?rq=1

Comment: The database was only on my computer as I developed the application. The only move will be to its new location, somewhere it can be accessed by more than one computer on the domain. In hindsight it was a pretty dumb idea but it seemed logical at the time. RE the link you provided, I did see this but was unable to picture it in my situation. The UNC share is the only space all the machines running the application have in common and i dont think this has sql installed.

Comment: Nothing dumb in regards to developing the database on your machine - it's standard practice. I don't think compact will be of any use as it is not multi user by design. You either need to install SQL on another machine or you will need to make the SQL Server instance on your machine visible to others on the network. This will involve enabling remote connections and setting up users with the correct permissions for the database. All of that is a bit beyond the scope of this question. You'll need to ask specific questions as you encounter any issues.